# Trying to debug old code. client credential code is deprecated

Tags: windows, .net-3.5

I'm trying to debug an old program, it is old in the sense that it's written in .net Framework 3.5. it is a Windows application communicating with a WCF and using the authenticationscheme Ntlm. I am using windows 10. 
in the code it uses windowsClientCredentials.AllowNtlm = true; when it creates the client. but AllowNtlm is nowadays deprecated, and in the Microsoft docs regarding this code it says this setting is now set in the local security policies. the problem there is that the organisation I'm working for has limited local admin rights, even to developers.

The problem is that it recognizes that the WCF hosted on my local iis uses Windows authentication, Ntlm and Negotiate are enabled. but Authentication fails.

"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM,Negotiate'."

My question is, is windowsClientCredentials.AllowNtlm deprecated in later .net framework versions, or did it become deprecated in later windows versions? I can request access to the local security policy settings. but since our IT department gives a default answer to any request a big fat no unless I give strong reason why I need it, I need to know if the reason is because of my windows version.

Answer (score 0):

Is your WCF project communicating with a webservice ?

In this case, you can add/remove provider in applicationhost.config file located under .vs/config directory of your web application project :

```
<windowsAuthentication enabled="false">
    <providers>
        <add value="Negotiate" />
        <add value="NTLM" />
    </providers>
</windowsAuthentication>
```

Hope it helps.